# Remove NULLs in result columns from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns in a table, where I want one of them split up in two based on the value in the other

Mytable:

```
xID  -  CompanyName
--------------------
250     Company1
250     Company2
130     Company3
1723    Company4
130     Company5
1723    Company6
```

My wished result

```
Column1  -  Column2
----------------------
Company1    Company4
Company2    Company6
Company3
Company4
```

My current result

```
Coulmn1  -  Column2
--------------------
Company1    Null
Company2    Null
Company3    Null
Null        Company4
Company5    Null
Null        Company6
```

My code

```
SELECT
case when xid in ('250', '130') then CompanyName END as 'Column1'
,case when xid in ('1723') then CompanyName END as 'Column2'
FROM Mytable
Where xid in ('250', '130', '1723')
```

What can I do? Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: I added sql-server, I hope that's okay now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN xid in (250, 130) THEN CompanyName END) as Column1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN xid in (1723) THEN CompanyName END) as Column12
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN xid IN (250, 130) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) ORDER BY CompanyName) as seqnum
      FROM Mytable t
      WHERE XID in (250, 130, 1723)
     ) t
GROUP BY seqnum
ORDER BY seqnum;
```

Note that I removed the single quotes around the literal values.  These look like numbers.  And `id`s usually are.  Don't use single quotes for numbers -- only for strings and dates.

Similarly, don't use single quotes for column aliases --  only for strings and dates.

Comment: Thank you! I added ")" between END and ORDER, but this worked perfectly.